# ManyToMany relationship join three tables with limit on result of third table limit on third table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three tables that are in ManyToMany relationship.
1.playlist
2.tracks
3.playlist_tracks

I want to retrieve 10 playlist with limit of 5 songs. how can i do it?
I have tried with this way..

```
select t1.id as playlistId, t2.playlist_id as pivot_playlist_id, t2.track_id as track_id 
from playlist t1 
join playlist_tracks t2 on t1.id = t2.playlist_id
left join (
    select t3.id as track_id , t3.is_published 
    from tracks t3
    where t3.is_published = 1 
    group by t3.id limit 5
    ) xx on t2.track_id = xx.track_id 
where t1.prior != 0 AND t1.is_published = 1 ;
```

but don't get proper result, as it is not applying limit on tracks. It returns all the songs of particular playlist. Where I am doing wrong> Please help me.Here is the DBfiddle for the same 
[sqlfiddle.com/#!9/feddbd/1](https://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/feddbd/1)

Comment: correlated subquery...  and JOINs.

Comment: can you describe it please ?

Comment: I would need a DBFiddle with some data in it, it's to complicated to do in my head...

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Version 8 offers new features that would assist here.

Comment: Make it 4 playlist with 3 songs, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I am using mysql version 5.6.38

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/feddbd/1 represents the schema for reference if any one want to help me for finding solution of my question

Answer (score 0):

Try this for limiting 5 songs for each playlist_track :

```
SET @playlist_id=-1;
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT track_id,
@row_number:=CASE
    WHEN @playlist_id= playlist_id THEN @row_number + 1
    ELSE 1
END AS track_number,
@playlist_id:=playlist_id as playlist_id
FROM playlist_tracks
ORDER BY playlist_id
) X WHERE track_number<=5
```

Comment: working in sqlfiddle `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/feddbd/17` but not working in mysql database.

Comment: what is the result in your mysql database?

Comment: sorry.. that was my typing mistake it is also working in mysql db.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i limit `playlist_number` also? and with some conditions like playlist must be active and track also be active with sorting on `prior ` number ? If i want to retrieve 5 `playlists` that are active then how can i do that? please tell me